# How can I add event to the calendar automatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, calendar, android-calendar

**How can i add event to the calendar automatically?** If I use this source code, it opens Calendar with filled entries, but I must click on save button to save it.

```
public class CalendarApplicationActivity extends Activity
{  

public static final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[] 
{  
        Calendars._ID, // 0  
        Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, // 1  
        Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME // 2  
};  


private static final int PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX = 2;  

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_application);  
}  

public void onClick(View view) 
{  

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);  
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");  
    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Learn Android");  
    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Home suit home");  
    intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Download Examples");  

    GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, 02);  
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,  
            calDate.getTimeInMillis());  
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,  
            calDate.getTimeInMillis());  

    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);  


    intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);  
    intent.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);  

    startActivity(intent);  

}  


}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I post you this code that is used in one of my app in the market. It adds automatically event to the user calendar. It doesn't use Intent that requires an user action.

```
public void addEvent(CalendarEvent evt) {
    //Log.d(Params.LOG_APP, "Insert event ["+evt+"]");

    try {
        Uri evtUri = ctx.getContentResolver().insert(getCalendarUri("events"), CalendarEvent.toContentValues(evt));
        Log.d(Params.LOG_APP, "" + evtUri);
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        //Log.e(Params.LOG_APP, "", t);
    }
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.ctx = context;
    this.baseUri = getCalendarUriBase();
}

private Uri getCalendarUri(String path) {
    return Uri.parse(baseUri + "/" + path);
}

private String getCalendarUriBase() {
    String calendarUriBase = null;
    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    try {
        managedCursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(calendars, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (managedCursor != null) {
        calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
    } else {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        try {
            managedCursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
        }

    }

    Log.d(Params.LOG_APP, "URI ["+calendarUriBase+"]");
    return calendarUriBase;
}
```

And for ICS and later

```
public void addEvent(CalendarEvent evt) {

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, CalendarEvent.toICSContentValues(evt));
    System.out.println("Event URI ["+uri+"]");

}
```

CalendarEvent is like

```
public static ContentValues toContentValues(CalendarEvent evt) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("calendar_id", evt.getIdCalendar());
    cv.put("title", evt.getTitle());
    cv.put("description", evt.getDescr());
    cv.put("eventLocation", evt.getLocation());
    cv.put("dtstart", evt.getStartTime());
    cv.put("dtend", evt.getEndTime());
    cv.put("eventStatus", 1);
    cv.put("visibility", 0);
    cv.put("transparency", 0);

    return cv;

}

public static ContentValues toICSContentValues(CalendarEvent evt) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, evt.getIdCalendar());
    cv.put(Events.TITLE, evt.getTitle());
    cv.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, evt.getDescr());
    cv.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, evt.getLocation());
    cv.put(Events.DTSTART, evt.getStartTime());
    cv.put(Events.DTEND, evt.getEndTime());

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();

    cv.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, tz.getDisplayName());
    /*
    cv.put(Events.STATUS, 1);
    cv.put(Events.VISIBLE, 0);
    cv.put("transparency", 0);

    return cv;
    */

    return cv;
}
```

Comment: I dont know ICS exactly,is it one way to save event automatically? I have errors with contentvalues. How can i describe non static values    calendarevent.java like this

Comment: CalendarEvent is like `public class CalendarEvent {
 
 private String title;
 private String descr;
 private String location;
 private long startTime;
 private long endTime;
 private String idCalendar; 
        // get and set methods` What kind of error do you have?

Comment: i took "04-19 15:09:51.645: E/ActivityThread(12428): Failed to find provider info for calendar" this error

Comment: You should verify in getCalendarUriBase the return value. It seems to me that you can't build correctly the URI because it says 'calendar'. Do you call setContext passing the context to the method?

Comment: @FrancescoAzzola what  baseUri Url do you use? 
is that private val baseUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3"

Answer (score 3):

I have used Following code to add event in my own created calendar

```
public void SyncEvent(long id, int meeting_id, String EventName,
   String Stime, String Etime, String Description) {

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));
 Date dt = null;
 Date dt1 = null;
 try {
  dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(Stime);
  dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(Etime);

  Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(dt);

  // beginTime.set(2013, 7, 25, 7, 30);
  beginTime.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
  cal.get(Calendar.DATE), cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
  cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

  Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(dt1);

  // endTime.set(2013, 7, 25, 14, 30);
  // endTime.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute);
  endTime.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
  cal.get(Calendar.DATE), cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
  cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

  ContentResolver cr = this.mContext.getContentResolver();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put(Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
  values.put(Events.DTEND, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
  values.put(Events.TITLE, EventName);
  values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, Description);
  values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, id);
  // values.put(Events._ID, meeting_id);
  values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

  Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
  long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
 } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Intents to communicate with the calendar provider, then, as you've noticed, the calendar app asks for confirmation from the user. This is because using Intents means you don't need to request any particular permissions.

By the way, Google recommends using Intents for interacting with the calendar.

However, if you do want automatic insertion of events, your app must have the `WRITE_CALENDAR` permission in the manifest.  Instead of using Intents, you use a ContentResolver.  You can see example code at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html in the section *Adding Events*.

Answer (score 1):

This code adds an event, and displays the event in the Calendar view. No clicking on 'save' / user interaction needed.

```
            long calID = 3;
            long startMillis = 0;
            long endMillis = 0;
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.set(2015, 6, 12, 7, 30);// set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute)
            startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(2015, 6, 12, 8, 30);
            endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,  tz.getID());
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
            long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());


            Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
            builder.appendPath("time");
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(builder.build());
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I am getting exception at this line  Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);