# Android Calendar Sync From Account Menu

Tags: android, android-emulator

Actually i want a calendar sync mechanism in my application where my application account shows  under account menu in device how to perform synchronization between my app data and android calendar.

How to create Events in calendar through application.Even I have tried to add account in calendar in emulator but it not allowing me to configure

Comment: Look [here][1]. It is shown how to add events. Does it help you?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068082/how-can-i-add-event-to-the-calendar-automatically/16068807#16068807

Comment: actually i solved the issue regarding adding Event but now facing problem of Event Duplication...how to avoid creation of duplicate event...